# Sharing Global Elements Across Mule Flows

Tags: mule-studio

What is the recommended way to permit import of global elements across flows. I am using mule studio version 3.4, by using the import tag I am able to access global elements defined in my but running the flow within mule studio generates following errors `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A service named already exists.`

```
<spring:beans>
<spring:import resource="name of flow xml where global elements are defined"/>
</spring:beans>
```

Is there an alternate way to share global elements?

Comment: where is the resource you are importing located?

Comment: I have two flows within the same project. i wish to share the connector configs across them

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If your `mule-config.xml` lies in a location , e.g. "packaged/serviceframework" then use below code snippet, i.e. by providing the path of the xml file instead of just the file name.

```
<spring:beans>
    <spring:import resource="classpath:packaged/serviceframework/mule-config.xml" />
</spring:beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bit late to the party but I just came across this issue and it was because I had imported a common mule config into another config that was in the same project/application.

In my case I had a single project set up in AnypointStudio that had two configs with completely separate flows. On top of this I had a third config with "common" sub-flows that I use in the other two. This common config was also in the same project. I had imported the common config into the other two configs but this is unnecessary as it's already available to both if they're all in the same project. This seems to mean the common config is brought in several times causing conficts with the common flows elements names.

Long story short...try remove imports like this that are in the same project:

```
<spring:beans>
    <spring:import resource="classpath:mule-common-config.xml" />
</spring:beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

Encountered this issue while trying to run mule application from Anypoint Studio 6.4.2. I believe the error is mule's way of complaining that the XML resource has been imported already. Checking for any duplicate imports could help in tackling this issue.